# Customized model values / output ngx-formly

Tags: angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am trying to use ngx-formly to render forms. (using the FormlyFormConfig Object) 
The form is rendering properly and i am getting model values as json object .

But is it possible that instead of setting the form fields values to model values i can set the values  to the FormlyFormConfig "defaultValue" field ?

if not , is it possible to set additional attributes to the model.

This is because my form is tied to a field ids which are coming from backend and wated to set the values to same same formfieldconfig so that the backend knows which field the values belong to .

[Here is the sample](https://angular-eaakfn.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understood your question, you can add a **default value** to the field.
For example:

**test.component.ts:**

```
  public form = new FormGroup({});
  public model = {};
  public options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
  public fields: FormlyFieldConfig[];

  this.fields = [{
      key: 'name',
      type: 'input',
      defaultValue: name, // you can add default value
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Name',
        placeholder: 'Name',
      },
    }];
```

**test.component.html:**

```
  <formly-form
    [form]="form"
    [fields]="fields"
    [model]="model"
    [options]="options"
  ></formly-form>
```